# CSS Rotate Icon: Not rotating correctly

Tags: css, rotation

Basically I'm trying to rotate -90 degrees a simple icon. The problem is that for some reason it keeps always a margin that ruins the rotation.

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6e8qapvd/2/

```
.list li a .arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.12s ease;
}

.list li a .arrow.open {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Any ideas? :/

Comment: Have you tried http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp ?

Comment: Your problem is that you're rotating the whole span and not the content in it.. I would use an image an rotate the image. Otherwise you have to guarante that the span will have the same with and height as that arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the initial value for the [`transform-origin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is `50% 50%`.

You could set it to `100% 50%`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/742z226c/)

```
.list li a .arrow.open {
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

Comment: The rotation still is not done perfectly. Basically it adds a margin that makes the rotation of the arrow around itself bugged :/ Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's it!! Transform-origin is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make the icon display: inline-block;

```
.list li a .arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.12s ease;
}

.list li a .arrow.open {
 display: inline-block;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```